# First Area Variation

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Could someone help me to solve this limit?

Let $X:\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3}$ imersion and 
${\LARGE \chi }_{t}:\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3}$, 
$t\in \left( -\epsilon ,\epsilon \right) $ a variation of $X$ in the form ${\LARGE \chi }\left( p,t\right) =X\left( p\right) +tf\left( p\right)
N\left( p\right) $
, where $N$ is normal of Gauss and $f:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ function differentiable.

Show that $$ A^{\prime }\left( 0\right) =\int_{\Omega }\left. \frac{d}{dt}\right\vert
_{t=0}{Jac}({\LARGE \chi }_{t})(p)dA.$$

$A^{\prime }\left( 0\right) =\underset{t\rightarrow 0}{\lim }\frac{1}{t}%
\left( A\left( t\right) -A\left( 0\right) \right) =\underset{t\rightarrow 0}{%
\lim }\frac{1}{t}\left( \int_{\Omega }\sqrt{E_{t}G_{t}-F_{t}^{2}}%
dudv-\int_{\Omega }\sqrt{EG-F^{2}}dudv\right) $

$=\underset{t\rightarrow 0}{\lim }\frac{1}{t}\int_{\Omega }\sqrt{%
E_{t}G_{t}-F_{t}^{2}}-\sqrt{EG-F^{2}}dudv=?$

Comment: What does $\text{Jac}(\chi_t)$ mean? After all, $\chi_t$ is a map from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I edited.

Comment: Be careful. What you've written doesn't make sense. The principal directions are in the tangent plane of the surface, not in $\Bbb R^2$. Are you sure you don't mean the standard basis vectors in $\Bbb R^2$, with $dA = du\,dv$? Then this is the standard way you compute the surface area, and all you've done is take $d/dt$ under the integral sign. There's no need to do anything with $E$, $F$, and $G$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes you are right.